# Combine FTP and Sales Cloud data through Data Filter?

Tags: marketing-cloud, filters, marketing-cloud-connect, ftp

This Marketing Cloud setup is integrated with Sales Cloud via Connect and FTP import activity.

So there are Contacts in separate DE's that are from FTP and there is data from SF via Synchronised Data Extensions.

Is there a way to use these two sources for a Data Filter and use its results to send Emails to?

Comment: Are you using data stream or an import activity for MC connect?

Comment: Hi, is there a way to verify which is it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could set up an Automation with a SQL query activity that joins the two data extensions and writes the result into another data extension which is then used for your email send. The query can also include filters if you like. If different filters should be applied leading to multiple segments, creating one joined data extension and filtered data extensions afterwards would be the best option in my opinion.

To keep the created data extension up to date you could create a triggered automation, that is started every time data is uploaded to the enhanced FTP.

**Related documentation:**

- [SQL Query Activity](http://help.marketingcloud.com/en/documentation/automation_studio/using_automation_studio_activities/using_the_query_activity/)
- [Import File Activity](http://help.marketingcloud.com/en/documentation/automation_studio/using_automation_studio_activities/use_an_import_activity/)
- [Triggered Automations](http://help.marketingcloud.com/en/documentation/automation_studio/triggered_automations/)
- [MSDN: Types of Joins](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/zt8wzxy4.aspx)